# Isomorphism between $G$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Suppose we have a group $G$ and $H$ a subgroup of $G$, $A$ a $G$-module. I am wondering how to show that $\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[H]} A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[G/H] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$. Specifically, why is the map $g\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[H]} m \mapsto \bar{g}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (g\cdot m)$ an isomorphism? I am having trouble with tensor product of group rings...

Comment: It's worth noting that any purely abstract approach is almost certainly doomed; were there an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\left[G\right]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}\left[H\right]}A\simeq\mathbb{Z}\left[G/H\right]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A$ natural in $G$, $H$, it would follow upon taking $A:\simeq\mathbb{Z}\left[H\right]$ that there be an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\left[G\right]\simeq\mathbb{Z}\left[G/H\right]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}\left[H\right]$ natural in $G$, $H$, an impossibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be seen by defining an inverse map as follows.

Let $(\bar g, m)$ be an element of $\Bbb Z[G/H] \times A$, where $g$ is an element of $G$. We then map it to $g \otimes _{\Bbb Z[H]} g^{-1}\cdot m\in \Bbb Z[G] \otimes_{\Bbb Z[H]} A$.

We need to check that this map is well defined, i.e. if $\bar {g'} = \bar{g}$ for $g, g' \in G$, then the images of $(\bar{g'}, m)$ and $(\bar g, m)$ are the same. This is easily checked, using the $\Bbb Z[H]$-linearity.

Thus we have a well defined map from $\Bbb Z[G/H] \times A$ to $\Bbb Z[G]\otimes_{\Bbb Z[H]} A$. It is $\Bbb Z$-bilinear, hence induced a $\Bbb Z$-linear map from $\Bbb Z[G/H]\otimes_\Bbb Z A$ to $\Bbb Z[G]\otimes_{\Bbb Z[H]} A$.

Now it suffices to check that this map is the inverse to your map, and that is quite obvious.